# Enabling Query cache in hibernate 3.3

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to enable query cache in hibernate 3.3 with the rest call implementation at DAO layer

I made this changes in hibernate-core-cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

and made changes in Hibernate_impexp.cfg.xml
commented the following code

```
<!-- Disable the second-level cache  
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider </property> -->
```

My code changes are as fallows

DAO implementation file as

```
public List<UserRoleEntity> getUserRolesByUserId(long userId)
    {
        getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true);
        return (List<UserRoleEntity>) this.getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(
                "getUserRolesByUserId", "userId", userId);
    }
```

when I am calling this rest call I can see hibernate query fired every time I am making these rest calls

What am I doing wrong ..???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling second level cache?

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Remember to Configure your entities to use the caching as well. By adding the

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
```

Annotation.

Comment: and [link]@Cacheable
[link]@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

I got an error cannot find symbol @Cacheable
[link]@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
and 
[link]@Cacheable at the time of build